# How can I pass data from one activity to another

Tags: android

I tried to look up something similar to what I want, but I can't find anything...

I want to pass data that I received from my database (`echo json_encode($response);` ) from one activity to another. The data is displayed in a `listview` and by clicking one item (in this case a 'category') it will take the user to second activity that displays a list of books (displayed in a `listview`).

My goal is to display results from received **data** (selected 'category' from first activity and selected 'book' from second activity) in a **third activity** (in here the user will have information about the book).

Any help will be great - a link to a tutorial that can help me solve this problem (well problem for me because I am new to all this), an example code or suggestions on how can I look it up...anything.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Intent for passing data from one activity to another activity. If you want to pass multiple types of data from one activity to another, Bundle will also be another choice for you. Look for tutorials regarding passing data through intent or bundle from one activity to another activity

Here is an Example to get you started

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),toActivityName.class);
i.putExtra("Key","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: thank you, i played with intent and got one part to work (for first activity to pass data to second activity), now i will try to pass that data (from the first one) and data from the second activity to the third activity i think now i will have to use bundle

Comment: yeah If those data's are of multiple types , then it would be easier to use bundle.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you so much for directions !